# Mixpanel on wordpress, how to pass title variable

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, mixpanel

Trying to setup Mixpanel on my wordpress site using a plugin I found.

The thing is, I need to edit the plugin so it will track the title of the page instead of the "event label". Tried a few options but all came back blank when I view the source so obviously I am missing the right way to do that.

Here's the code:

```
  function insert_event()
{
$event_label = self::get_post_event_label(); 
$settings = (array) get_option( 'mixpanel_settings' );


if(!isset($settings['token_id'])) {
  self::no_mixpanel_token_found();
  return false;  
}

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
     mixpanel.register_once({ 'first_referrer': document.referrer });
   mixpanel.track(\"$event_label\", {'referrer': document.referrer });
</script> "; 
return true; 
}
```

so, I need to replace `$event_label` with `wp_title` (I think...) outside the loop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

With a little help from a friend I managed to solve it and thought I should share:

```
$event_label = self::get_post_event_label(); 
if(empty($event_label)) $event_label = wp_title( ' ', false, 'right' );
```

This was changed and now it works.